# Buffered and Unbuffered Writes in Golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to get the performance difference between buffered and unbuffered write.

**Buffered Write code**

```
func writeFileBuff(n int) {
    b := []byte("hi")
    buf := bufio.NewWriter(fileHandleBuf)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        buf.Write(b)
    }
    buf.Flush()
}
```

**Unbuffered Write code**

```
func writeFile(n int) {
    b := []byte("hi")
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        fileHandle.Write(b)
    }
}
```

And here is the `go bench` result:

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: awesomeProject/write
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1038NG7 CPU @ 2.00GHz
BenchmarkWriteFile-8                5704          10588462 ns/op
BenchmarkWriteFileBuf-8            26428            119679 ns/op
```

Well, seems like `buffered writer` is thousands of times faster than `unbuffered`, but I have some concerns:

- Is it so many times faster? My code is comparing correctly?
- Today I'm using `unbuffered write` because I have concerns about losing data since buffered write will store in memory and later on write to disk, but during this time my app might crash and I can lose that data.

Comment: Even without using the buffered writer you can lose data if your app crashes. Use whichever makes your app more efficient.

Comment: what do you mean @JimB ? Using unbuffered the data is written to disk right away, no?

Comment: Yes, it's less likely but the OS and hardware can have buffers too -- you're not guaranteeing the data has been committed to permanent storage. You need to ask yourself if it's worth making every single IO operation orders of magnitude slower, just for the incredibly small chance that your app crashes while buffering the data. There's a reason that buffered IO is the default in almost all scenarios.